# Why is a Web Site project not serving pages except through IIS?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2012, iis-7.5

I have inherited quite a complex web site project, and when I run it in VS 2012 under the default "Use default Web server" setting for "Server", it serves the login page correctly, under the base URL `http://localhost:45632` and I can log in nicely. Then, when I click a menu item with the URL `http://localhost:45632/Apps/Visitors/General.aspx`, I get a good and plain 404.

If I then create a web site (not application under the default site) for it in IIS 7.5; set the physical directory to the project's source folder; give it a host name, `xtjethro.local`, and edit my hosts file to point that host name to 127.0.0.1; set the web site project to use a custom server, with a base URL of and finally, browse the site from its context menu, it serves its pages under the base url `http://xtjethro.local/` instead of `http://localhost:45632`, everything works fine.

Then, if I set the web site project to use a custom server with a base URL of `http://xtjethro.local`, and restart VS2012, running it as administrator, everything works from there as well.

I would like to know why `http://localhost:45632/Apps/Visitors/General.aspx` doesn't work under VS2012, but `http://xtjethro.local/Apps/Visitors/General.aspx` does work under IIS.

Comment: I realize the answer to this is probably no but that wouldn't happen to be a virtual directory set up in IIS would it?

Comment: @MarkRucker No, there are no virtual directories under the default site in IIS connected to the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Visual Studio development web-server usually runs the site under a virtual directory which matches your project name. That would mean that the URL of your page should be `http://localhost:45632/YourProjectName/Apps/Visitors/General.aspx`. If you create an application under the default site in IIS, you will probably see the same problem.

You'll need to change the way your links are generated. Instead of using `/Apps/...`, use `~/Apps/...` - ASP.NET will automatically resolve `~/` to the base path of the site.

Comment: VS should know about the site (not under the default site). I have specified a custom server and given it that host as a URL base.

Comment: @ProfK: But if you have, for example: `<a href="/Apps/Visitors/General.aspx">`, VS won't change that URL. You need to use an app-relative URL with a server control for ASP.NET to expand the path properly.